# CopyFiles Task not picking up files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

Using Azure DevOps YAML in a database project build and release pipeline

This bit of code correctly picks up my four dacpac files, I can see these being copied in the console

```
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: Copy build output to artifacts staging
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
        flattenFolders: true
        Contents: '**\bin\**\*.dacpac'
        TargetFolder: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
```

This bit of code correctly picks up my publish files, I can see these being copied in the console

```
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: Copy build output to artifacts staging
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
        flattenFolders: true
        Contents: '**\PublishProfile\*.publish.xml'
        TargetFolder: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
```

This bit of code reports "zero files found"

```
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: Copy build output to artifacts staging
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
        flattenFolders: true
        Contents: |
          '**\bin\**\*.dacpac'
          '**\PublishProfile\*.publish.xml'
        TargetFolder: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
```

This pipe multiline syntax is all over the examples
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#examples

I've also used Get-ChildItem to doubly confirm that the files exist.

It seems like | / multiline doesn't work as described.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As usual, as I write this I checked in detail and the one difference between my code and the example was single quotes.

So it works if you remove single quotes.

***Does anyone even QA this stuff?***

```
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: Copy build output to artifacts staging
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
        flattenFolders: true
        Contents: |
          # NOTE THESE PATHS ARE NOT SURROUNDED BY SINGLE QUOTES
          # EVEN THOUGH THIS WORKS IN THE SINGLE LINE VERSION
          **\bin\**\*.dacpac
          **\PublishProfile\*.publish.xml
        TargetFolder: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
```

### Other hot tips to save you hours:

- Use this to list files to help troubleshoot missing files

  ```
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      workingDirectory: $(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)
      script: ls -R
  ```
- Remember Linux is CASE SENSITIVE - get the case wrong and it won't find your files
- As of right now, you can't parameterise service connections. Maybe that will change in future
- It's possible to get indentation wrong in YAML and it gives you no clues

This code makes all the variables in the variable group `TST` available (these are under "Library" not "Environment" - go figure)

```
variables:
- group: TST
```

This code (with extra indentation) doesn't throw an error or give any clues, it just doesn't make any variables available. All your variables like `$(MyVariable)` will be treated as literals

```
variables:
  - group: TST
```